# String input, parsing, split

Tags: java

I need to write a program that makes a user to type string date (ex. 10/21) once, and convert that string into integers. I suppose splitting is necessary before parsing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConvertDates {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please input a date (mm/dd): ");
      String k = input.next();
      k = String.split("/");
      int mm = Integer.parseInt(k);
      int dd = Integer.parseInt(k);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you split a string, you don't get a string, you get an array of strings. So you would need to call

```
String[] k2 = k.split("/");
```

then you can get your month and day with

```
int mm = Integer.parseInt(k2[0]);
int dd = Integer.parseInt(k2[1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] tokens = k.split("/");
int mm = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int dd = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
```

Since [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method returns string array, you have to use above code.

Answer (score 3):

[String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns a `String` array. You need to use the elements of the returned Array:

```
String[] strings = k.split("/");
int mm = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
int dd = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or even

```
   Scanner dates = new Scanner(k);
   dates.useDelimiter("/");
   int mm = dates.nextInt();
   int dd = dates.nextInt();
```

and then you don't need to parse the integer